# Java: I have a List of cars that i wanna sort by registrationNumber(String) that is inside one of the elements in the list

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I have a ist in java, that has car objects inside, and inside one of the car objects is a String thats named RegistrationNumber, and i wanna sort the list by that
    List cars = new ArrayList();

```
public Collection<ICar> sortedByRegistrationNumber() {

}
```

Comment: Use `Collections.sort` and let the `Car` implement `Comparable`

Comment: @SilverNak I think sort only exist inside List interface (as Collection may be unordered and thus sorting them wouldn't have much sense) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (list.size() > 0) {
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Car>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(final Car object1, final Car object2) {
          return object1.getRegNo().compareTo(object2.getRegNo());
      }
  });
}
```

If you are using **Java 8** then you can do it like this:

```
list.stream()
  .sorted((object1, object2) -> object1.getRegNo().compareTo(object2.getRegNo()));
```

Comment: does it return the list sorted?

Comment: Yes. As registration number is a string, so it will be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond and help

Comment: how would i make it if i needed to sort it by a number now and not a string?

Comment: It's the same. the compare function will sort it from lowest to highest number

Comment: You don't have to change anything. It will sort automatically according to the type.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There are two ways to do it.

1. **Using Comparable Interface:** In this your bean itself is to be implemented with an interface called comparable and override a method compareTo in which you will write logic on which basis you want classes to compare in your case reg No. The problem is if in future you want to have a sorting on the basis of let us assume make year or anything else you cant do that.

   ```
   public class Car implements Comparable<Car>{

       private String regNo;

           public Car(String regNo){
               super();
               this.regNo = regNo;
           }

           public String getRegNo(){
               return regNo;
           }

           public void setRegNo(String regNo){
               this.regNo = regNo;
           }

           @Override
           public int compareTo(Car o){  

               // Here when we compare if both the variables are equal return 0
               if(this.regNo.equals(o.getRegNo())){
                   return 0;  
               // If first one is bigger than the latter return 1
               }else if(this.regNo.compareTo(o.getRegNo()) > 0){
                   return 1; 
               // else return 0
               }else{
                   return -1;  
               }
           }  
       }
   ```

   **To Test:**

   ```
     Car c1 =  new Car("Z");
     Car c2 =  new Car("A");
     Car c3 =  new Car("C");
     Car c4 =  new Car("B");
     List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(c1);
     list.add(c2);
     list.add(c3);
     list.add(c4);

     Collections.sort(list);
     System.out.println(list);
   ```
2. **Using Comparator Interface:** To remove the Comparable's drawback Comparator comes to the rescue. In comparator you will create a new class called and implement it with Comparator interface. You will have to override the comparator's compare method which takes two arguments which are the objects you want to compare. How this helps is you can have multiple comparators based on the need and you just need to pass the Comparator to the `Collections.sort` method as and argument which will sort it automatically. Below is the example for the same class. Here you dont need to implement the imple,

   ```
   public class Car2
   {
       private String regNo;

       public Car2(String regNo){
           super();
           this.regNo = regNo;
       }

       public String getRegNo(){
           return regNo;
       }


       public void setRegNo(String regNo){
           this.regNo = regNo;
       }
   }
   ```

   **Comparator class**

   ```
   public class CarComparator implements Comparator<Car2>
   {
       @Override
       public int compare(Car2 o1, Car2 o2)
       {
           Car2 c1 = (Car2) o1;
           Car2 c2 = (Car2) o2;

           //TODO check for nulls
           if(c1.getRegNo().equals(c2.getRegNo())){
               return 0;  
           }else if(c1.getRegNo().compareTo(c2.getRegNo()) > 0){
               return 1; 
           }else{
               return -1;  
           }
       }  
   }
   ```

   **Test**

   ```
   Car2 c1 =  new Car2("Z");
   Car2 c2 =  new Car2("A");
   Car2 c3 =  new Car2("C");
   Car2 c4 =  new Car2("B");
   List<Car2> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(c1);
   list.add(c2);
   list.add(c3);
   list.add(c4);

       Collections.sort(list,new CarComparator());
       System.out.println(list);
   ```

You can find more information here:

1.[Comparable](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework)
2.[Comparator](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Collection<ICar> sortedByRegistrationNumber(List<ICar> cars) {
       return Collections.sort(cars, new Comparator<ICar>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ICar o1, ICar o2) {
            return o1.getRegistrationNumber().compareTo(o2.getRegistrationNumber())
        }
    });
   }
```

OR

```
public Collection<ICar> sortedByRegistrationNumber() {
   return Collections.sort(this.cars, new Comparator<ICar>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ICar o1, ICar o2) {
        return o1.getRegistrationNumber().compareTo(o2.getRegistrationNumber())
    }
});
}
```